# Restrictions on use of the Google Places JavaScript API?

Tags: google-places-api

I'm using JavaScript Places Library
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

However, I can't find how to set the API key.
Is there a limit to the number of times I can use this Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Places Library does not require an API key to implement. The library however is limited by requests per minute, per user. If a user exceeds this limit the request will return the status `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`

Comment: Thank you for answer.

There was document about this restriction to The Google Places API.
http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/places/#Limits

Therefore, I was getting the API key.
This restriction or JavaScript API and will not matter?
In other words, Can I send many requests per day?

Comment: The restriction on the Google Places API that is documented is different to the restriction on the JavaScript API Places Library. The JavaScript API Places Library does not have a documented limit, but if a user performs more queries than deemed acceptable by Google in a minute, they will receive the `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` status in response to a request.